# Show that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n+1} \sum_{j=0}^{j=n} a_j*b_{n-j} = a*b$ when $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = a$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty} b_n = b$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, limits

This is a problem from Remmert, Schumacher, *Theory of Functions*, Chapter 0

Let $(a_n)_n, (b_n)_n$ two complex sequences with $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = a$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty} b_n = b$

Show that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n+1} \sum_{j=0}^{j=n} a_j*b_{n-j} = a*b$

I wanted to split the sum like this

$|\frac{1}{n+1} \sum_{j=0}^{j=n} a_j*b_{n-j} -a*b| =$
$\frac{1}{n+1} |\sum_{j=0}^{j=n} (a_j*b_{n-j} -a*b)|$ $\leq$

$\frac{1}{n+1} |\sum_{j=0}^{j=N_0} (a_j*b_{n-j} -a*b)|$ +
$\frac{1}{n+1} |\sum_{j=N_0+1}^{j=N_1} (a_j*b_{n-j} -a*b)|$ + $\frac{1}{n+1} |\sum_{j=N_1+1}^{j=n} (a_j*b_{n-j} -a*b)|$

where I wanted that for the middle terms, $j$ and $n-j$ should be big enough such that $a_j*b_{n-j}$ are close to $a*b$ and the other terms shouldn’t matter, because of the fixed $N_0, N_1$. Unfortunately I didn’t get anything meaningful. Can you give me a hint?

Comment: Is $*$ the usual complex product?

Comment: Yes, it is the usual multiplication.

Comment: Thank you for the link! I was searching for something like this, but couldn’t find it before.

Comment: @infinite1: Found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Clim_%7Bn%5Cto%5Cinfty%7D%20%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bn%2B1%7D%20%5Csum_%7Bj%3D0%7D%5E%7Bn%7D%20a_j%20b_%7Bn-j%7D%20%3D%20a%20b%24&p=1). See also https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5048/42969 and https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/24978/42969 on Meta.

Comment: Better to write $ab$ than $a*b.$